# VBA Sum Values Between Days of Week

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following set of data in Excel (Sheet Name: 'WorkingSheet')

```
 | A               | B   | C       | D       | E
1| 14 October 2013 | Mon | 9:28:30 | 0:19:14 |
2| 15 October 2013 | Tue | 9:25:20 | 0:05:39 |
3| 16 October 2013 | Wed | 9:29:07 | 0:06:58 |
4| 17 October 2013 | Thu | 9:27:02 | 0:04:25 |
5| 18 October 2013 | Fri | 9:32:11 | 0:01:29 |
6| 19 October 2013 | Sat | 9:28:08 | 3:12:45 | 60:40:48
7| 20 October 2013 | Sun | 7:59:41 | 0:00:00 | 7:59:41 
8| 21 October 2013 | Mon | 9:26:52 | 0:13:42 |
9|  22 October 2013 | Tue | 9:26:51 | 0:14:32 |
10| 23 October 2013 | Wed | 9:35:06 | 0:08:14 |
11| 24 October 2013 | Thu | 9:19:13 | 0:10:49 |
12| 25 October 2013 | Fri | 6:50:44 | 3:06:47 | 48:32:50
13| 28 October 2013 | Mon | 9:30:21 | 0:11:49 |
14| 29 October 2013 | Tue | 9:46:43 | 0:09:27 |
15| 30 October 2013 | Wed | 9:28:31 | 0:15:15 |
16| 31 October 2013 | Thu | 9:31:04 | 0:16:04 | 39:09:14
```

I would like to put a VBA script together that calculates the value in 'E'.

'E' needs to SUM the values in 'C' and 'D' from Monday of Week to Saturday (or last day available in week) (E6 = SUM(C1:D6))
For Sundays just equals the SUM of that single day (Sunday)

Can this be done?

I'm new to all of this so please excuse me if this is a silly question.

If there is anything else that you would like to know please let me know.

Thanks so much.

---

EDIT: Addition.

Ok, so I'm trying to make something up from the bits and pieces I've found, so far I have this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lw As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim hDate As Date
Dim hc As Range


hDate = dhLastDayInWeek(Range("A1"))
    lw = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Range("A1:A" & lw)
    If dhLastDayInWeek(c.Value) = hDate Then

    Else
        c.Offset(-1, 5).Value = Application.Sum(Range("C1:C27"))
        hDate = dhLastDayInWeek(CDate(c))
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

With This function to find date

```
Function dhLastDayInWeek(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Date
' Last Day being Saturday +6
dhLastDayInWeek = dtmDate - Weekday(dtmDate, vbUseSystem) + 6

End Function
```

I now just need to figure out how to change the Application.Sum(Range("C1:C27")) to sum from hDate Cell to where the date does not equal ..

Getting there, not too bad for never having done this before :S

Comment: it can be done but you need to show us what you have tried to solve this problem. People often misunderstand the concept of Stack Overflow so bear in mind that we do not write code for people. We help people understand why they have problems in the code they already wrote and how to fix them. I see no relation to programming in your question so I'd recommend [Super User](http://superuser.com) as more appropriate site for questions like yours.

Comment: @mehow Thanks, I'll try bring some examples of things that I've tried. Currently I'm just a little lost and was hoping that someone might offer a suggestion that I could build off of.
As much as a an answer dump would be great the only way I'm going to learn is by building and tweaking myself.

Comment: look at [`=SUMIFS()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)

Comment: @mehow Thank you for the comments you left, they were a great help and helped me identify some new techniques that I could try and use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives a good result:

As you define column A as DateTime value, we loop over this column, until a null cell is found. C and D columns are time values in **hh:mm:ss** format.

```
Sub sof20193038SumPerWeek()
  Dim i, wDay, wDayLast, dblTotal
  Dim bEmpty
  Dim dtmDate

  i = 1
  wDayLast = -1
  bEmpty = False
  dblTotal = 0

  Do While (Not bEmpty)
    dtmDate = Range("A" & i).Value
    bEmpty = IsEmpty(dtmDate)
    If (bEmpty) Then
      Range("E" & (i - 1)).Value = dblTotal
      Exit Do
    End If
    '
    ' get the weekday in [1,7]:
    '
    wDay = Weekday(dtmDate, vbMonday)
    '
    ' last existent weekday, neither saturday nor sunday:
    '
    If (wDay < wDayLast) Then
      If (Not ((wDayLast = 6) Or (wDayLast = 7))) Then
        Range("E" & (i - 1)).Value = dblTotal
        dblTotal = 0
      End If
    End If
    '
    ' sum up C and D columns:
    '
    dblTotal = dblTotal + Range("C" & i).Value + Range("D" & i).Value
    '
    ' weekend: ie, saturday or sunday:
    '
    If ((wDay = 6) Or (wDay = 7)) Then
      Range("E" & i).Value = dblTotal
      dblTotal = 0
    Else
      Range("E" & i).Value = Null
    End If
    '
    wDayLast = wDay
    '
    ' prepare for the next row:
    '
    i = i + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. 
I've run through it a few times to make sure I understand what you've done and it's great. Its given me a few ideas of how I can improve other things that I've done.
As mentioned I've only just started playing with VBA so every new piece of code I get to play with is something new to learn from :)

Comment: +1 great answer, why is the font at cell E12 different than others :O ? hehe